# MKAnnonationView Tapping Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I want to navigate to next class through tap on MKAnnotationView on MKMapView. How can I do this plz give some sample code for this.

I had done this code..explained below..

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)customAnnotationView
{
       //Here Push to another view controller
}
```

One problem is that when clicking on one item, this method calls and It will navigate to other class but when I come back and again tap on the same item this method not called.

Please help me to solve me this problem...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to implement this method:-

edited:-

you need to implement following method.

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    NSLog(@"touch");
    [mapView deselectAnnotation:view animated:NO];
    firstVC *aa=[[[firstVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"firstVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:aa animated:YES];

}

 -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    NSLog(@"notouch");
    firstVC *aa=[[[firstVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"firstVC" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:aa animated:YES];

}
```

previous:-

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{    
    CompanyDetail  *detail = [[CompanyDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"CompanyDetail" bundle:nil];       
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES]; 
}

Make sure you do 

UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

in your 
`- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation` method

Comment: this method not getting called when I tap any annotation on Mapview,Can u plz help me to solve it

Comment: this method will get called when you will click on disclosure button of your annotation.Have you added your button when you show pin annotation

Comment: I am not adding any disclosure button but adding image on it using custom annotations and clicking this annotation I want to do this..can u help me

Comment: no this is mapview delegate method and it gets called when accessory button gets tapped.

Comment: can u tell me why the method that I had written is not getting called every time

Comment: Can u please tell me what to write in this method and when this method getting called?

Comment: Release annotation in this method?